Checking whether the antiderivative I got from an integral calculator is correct?
This antiderivative calculator shows that the antiderivative of :

$ \ln\left(\sqrt{z^{2} + bz + c} + a\right)$

w.r.t $z$ is :

$$\frac{2a \left(\ln\left(\frac{\left|2 \left(\sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} + z\right) - \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + b\right|}{\left|2z + b\right|}\right) - \ln\left(\frac{\left|2 \sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} - 2z - \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - b\right|}{\left|2z + b\right|}\right)\right) + \left(2z + b\right) \ln\left(\sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} + a\right) - 2z}{2} + \frac{\left(4c - b^{2} - 4a^{2}\right) \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - 2a} \left(2 \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} \sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} - 4c + b^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + 2a} \left(2z + b\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - 2a} \sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + 2a}}$$

which is equal to :

$${a \left(\ln\left(\frac{\left|2 \left(\sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} + z\right) - \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + b\right|}{\left|2z + b\right|}\right) - \ln\left(\frac{\left|2 \sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} - 2z - \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - b\right|}{\left|2z + b\right|}\right)\right) + \left(z + \frac{b}{2}\right) \ln\left(\sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} + a\right)} + \frac{\left(4c - b^{2} - 4a^{2}\right) \arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - 2a} \left(2 \sqrt{4c - b^{2}} \sqrt{z \left(z + b\right) + c} - 4c + b^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} \sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + 2a} \left(2z + b\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} - 2a} \sqrt{\sqrt{4c - b^{2}} + 2a}}\\ - z\\
=\\
(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)$$


My task is to check whether this antiderivative's derivative is the original function:
$ \ln\left(\sqrt{z^{2} + bz + c} + a\right)$
MY CHECK
The derivative of $(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)$ w.r.t $z$ must be the original function :
$ \ln\left(\sqrt{z^{2} + bz + c} + a\right)$

Let:
$A=\sqrt{4c-b^2}$
$B=\sqrt{4c-b^2-4a^2}$
$f=2 \sqrt{z^2 + bz + c}$
$g=2z + b$


Derivative of $(1)$ w.r.t $z$ :
$(1) = a \ln (f-A+g)-a \ln (f-A-g)$
Taking its derivative w.r.t $z$, we get :
$\left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A+g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g+f}{f}\right) - \left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A-g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g-f}{f}\right)$


Derivative of $(2)$ w.r.t $z$ :
$(2) = \dfrac{g}{2} . \ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2} + a \right)$
Taking its derivative w.r.t $z$, we get :
$\dfrac{g^2}{f^2 +2af}+ \ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a    \right)$


Derivative of $(3)$ w.r.t $z$ :
$(3) = B \tan^{-1} \left( \dfrac{B(f-A)}{(2a+A)(g)} \right)$
Taking its derivative w.r.t $z$, we get :
$\dfrac{(2 B^2 g^2)(A+2a) (g^2 - f + A)}{(A+2a)^2 g^4 + B^2 g^2 (f-A)^2}$


Derivative of $(4)$ w.r.t $z$ :
$(4) = -z$
Taking its derivative w.r.t $z$, we get :
$-1$

Now :

$$\dfrac {d[(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)]}{dz} = \ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a    \right)$$

That is :

$$\left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A+g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g+f}{f}\right) - \left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A-g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g-f}{f}\right)\\
+ \dfrac{g^2}{f^2 +2af}+ \ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a    \right)\\
+ \dfrac{(2 B^2 g^2)(A+2a) (g^2 - f + A)}{(A+2a)^2 g^4 + B^2 g^2 (f-A)^2}\\
-1=\ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a    \right)$$

That is :

$$\left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A+g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g+f}{f}\right) - \left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A-g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g-f}{f}\right)\\
+ \dfrac{g^2}{f^2 +2af}\\
+ \dfrac{(2 B^2 g^2)(A+2a) (g^2 - f + A)}{(A+2a)^2 g^4 + B^2 g^2 (f-A)^2}\\
=1$$

Now if I am able to prove this last equation, my checking would be complete. Any shortcuts or hints in proving this last equation ?

if you used an online antiderivative calculator, here's an online derivative calculator - https://www.derivative-calculator.net/

The derivative calculator is showing a huge expression. What I am expecting is the derivative to be the original function? The calculator also says both the expressions are equivalent, but doesn't show how ?

The result is false, definitely. I propose to do $$\int \sqrt{((z-a)\ (z-b) \ + \  c} \ dz$$ instead with a shorter result and identify the roots later.

Are you interested in the antiderivative of the said function or only in checking the result given by the online calculator in the end ?

The calculator says "It was assumed that $a\gt 0,4c\gt b^2,\sqrt{4c-b^2}\gt 2a$".
This answer assumes that your $a,b,c$ satisfy them.
You can use $$g^2=(f-A)(f+A)\tag5$$
$$B^2=(A-2a)(A+2a)\tag6$$

For (1),
$$\left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A+g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g+f}{f}\right) - \left(\dfrac{2a}{f-A-g}\right) \left(\dfrac{g-f}{f}\right)$$
$$=\frac{2a(g+f)(f-A-g)-2a(g-f)(f-A+g)}{f(f-A+g)(f-A-g)}\tag7$$
Using $(5)$, we have
$$\begin{align}\text{numerator of $(7)$}&=2a(2f^2-2fA-2g^2)
\\&=4a(f^2-fA-g^2)
\\&=4a(A^2-fA)
\\&=4aA(A-f)\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}\text{denominator of $(7)$}&=f((f-A)^2-g^2)
\\&=f(f^2-2fA+A^2-g^2)
\\&=f(2A^2-2fA)
\\&=2fA(A-f)\end{align}$$
so
$$(7)=\frac{2a}{f}$$

For (3), I think it is wrong that
$$\dfrac{(2 B^2 g^2)(A+2a) (g^2 - f + A)}{(A+2a)^2 g^4 + B^2 g^2 (f-A)^2}$$
It should be
$$\dfrac{(2 B^2 g^2)(A+2a) (\color{red}{\frac{g^2 - f^2 + fA}{f}})}{(A+2a)^2 g^4 + B^2 g^2 (f-A)^2}\tag8$$
since, using $f'=\frac{2g}{f}$, we get
$$\begin{align}&\bigg(B\tan^{-1}\bigg(\frac{B(f-A)}{(2a+A)g}\bigg)\bigg)'
\\\\&=\frac{B}{\bigg(\frac{B(f-A)}{(2a+A)g}\bigg)^2+1}\times\frac{B\bigg(\frac{2g^2}{f}-2(f-A)\bigg)}{(2a+A)g^2}
\\\\&=\frac{2B^2(2a+A)^2g^2}{B^2(f-A)^2+(2a+A)^2g^2}\times\frac{\frac{g^2}{f}-(f-A)}{(2a+A)g^2}
\\\\&=(8)\end{align}$$
Now, $(8)$ can be simplified as
$$\dfrac{2 B^2(A+2a) (g^2 - f^2 + fA)}{f\bigg((A+2a)^2 g^2 + B^2 (f-A)^2\bigg)}\tag9$$
Using $(5)(6)$, we have
$$\begin{align}&\text{numerator of $(9)$}\\&=2(A-2a)(A+2a)^2(-A^2 + fA)
\\&=2A(A-2a)(A+2a)^2(f-A)\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}&\text{denominator of $(9)$}\\&=f\bigg((A+2a)^2 g^2 + B^2 (f-A)^2\bigg)
\\&=f\bigg((A+2a)^2(f-A)(f+A) + (A-2a)(A+2a) (f-A)^2\bigg)
\\&=f(A+2a)(f-A)\bigg((A+2a)(f+A)+(A-2a)(f-A)\bigg)
\\&=f(A+2a)(f-A)(4aA+2Af)
\\&=2Af(A+2a)(f-A)(f+2a)\end{align}$$
so
$$(9)=\frac{(A - 2 a) (A+2 a)}{f (f+2 a)}$$

So, we want to prove that
$$\frac{2a}{f}+\dfrac{f^2-A^2}{f(f+2a)}+ \ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a\right)+\frac{(A - 2 a) ( A+2a)}{f ( f+2a)}-1=\ln \left( \dfrac{f}{2}+a\right)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\frac{2a}{f}+\dfrac{f^2-A^2}{f(f+2a)}+\frac{(A - 2 a) ( A+2a)}{f (f+2 a)}=1$$
We can see that this does hold since the LHS is equal to
$$\frac{2a(f+2a)+f^2-A^2+A^2-4a^2}{f(f+2a)}=\frac{2af+f^2}{f(f+2a)}=1$$

Thank you very much bro.... However I am amazed by your ability to see the hidden expressions before looking. Can I get your email for other helps in mathematics ?
